# Integration Response cannot map array of items

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

My goal is to to be able to produce a csv file. For now just trying to return a list of ids in JSON.

I'm struggling to map a response, so my JSON is:

```
{
"items": [
        {
            "id": "2017-07-02_n_Eleana Qorgyle",
            "groupId": "n_2017-07"}
]
}
```

and my model is

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "Log",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "items": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": { "type": "string" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My Velocity template is ...

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
  "items" : [
##TODO: Update this foreach loop to reference array from input json
#foreach($elem in $inputRoot.items)
 {
    "id" : "foo"
  } 
#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
]
}
```

However, I am getting this output:

```
{
    "items": []
}
```

Have I missed something? $inputRoot.body outputs everything, but iterating is an issue.

Comment: I tried with the setting you post here. I am able to get ```{"items" : [{ "id" : "foo" }]}```. I guess you might forget to deploy your API.

Comment: Yep, api is deployed,  just putting indexRoot.items works ok. Iterating through it is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
  #set($inputRoot = $input.path('$')) {
      "items" : [
       #foreach($elem in $inputRoot.items){
        "id" : "$elem.get('id')"
       } 
       #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
       #end
      ]
   }
```

Thanks!